# How to set multiple `core.excludesfile` in `.gitconfig`?

Tags: git

I'm syncing `~/.gitconfig` and `~/.gitignore` files in ubuntu and Mac by using dropbox and created symlink for it.

And `excludesfile` is declared like this.

```
[core]
        editor = /usr/bin/vim
        excludesfile = /Users/username/.gitignore
```

The problem is home directory differs by os, therefore I need multiple setting for excludesfile.

Is it possible to define multiple `core.excludesfile`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can only have a single `core.excludesfile`; the last setting is the one that's used. However, you don't need multiple files: git supports `~` as an abbreviation for your home directory.

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

In general, if you really needed to have multiple excludes files, the simplest solution would be to generate a single file that's the concatenation of the others, and update it whenever one of the files changes.

Comment: My `.gitconfig` is actually under version control by git. Unfortunately, git expands `~` to be the full path to `$HOME` and updates the `.gitconfig` itself with the absolute path. That behavior is fine, but then it shows up as an unstaged change, so I use `git update-index --assume-unchanged .gitconfig` to ignore the expansion (along with the rest of the file).

Comment: @Dolph [meta-tag:status-norepro] What did you do to cause `~` to be expanded? I get: `git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'; git config --global core.excludesfile` → `~/.gitignore` (git 1.7.9.5)

Comment: @Dolph Most likely this was a shell expansion; after all, if you do `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore` then what is actually run is `git config --global core.excludesfile /path/to/home/.gitignore`.

Comment: @Gilles, note also that per [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), the file `~/.config/git/ignore` if it exists is globally ignored automatically, with no global configuration necessary.